# How to download previous version of tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

For some reason, I want to use some previous version of tensorflow('tensorflow-**-.whl', not source code on github) and where can I download the previous version and how can I know the corresponding `cuda version` that is compatible.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can always download the previous version of tensorflow version

from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#download-and-setup)

Here on the top left you can change the version

[image]

Comment: There are no other versions below 0.10 there =(

Comment: upd. there some as branches on github repo, ie.:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.8

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 57):

It works for me, since I have 1.6

```
pip install tensorflow==1.5
```

Comment: Easiest solution by far, this answer needs more upvotes! An example installing TF 1.4.1 GPU version: `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1`

Comment: @DavidParks Yes, it maybe the easiest solution now. Actually, TF didn't support `pip install tensorflow-XX=XXX` at the moment when the problem was posted.

Comment: @luhao , with double "=="

Comment: This has been broken for some reasons. One can find and download legacy versions from the `Release history` page of tensorflow or tensorflow-gpu in pypi.org.

Comment: This will uninstall newer version and install version specified, it works for me.

Comment: pip install tensorflow==1.15  in 2020 Jan

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5

Comment: @AndreasK. which python version do you have? I think 1.15 version of Tensorflow is not available for new python versions. I had python3.5.3 when I was testing this tensorflow command.

Comment: Yeap, I have 3.8 and that was the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Find available versions (some example results shown):

```
$ curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow |xmllint --format - |grep whl

<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
```

You can, of course, filter the results further by piping through additional instances of `grep`.

Pick the version you want and install for Python with `pip`...

```
$ TFVERSION=linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
$ pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/$(TFVERSION)
```

---

Note: `cp27` in the list above indicates compatibility with Python version 2.7.

Comment: Google must have changed something. This command does not return anything now.

Comment: The commad is no longer working: **permission denied**.

Answer (score 6):

The above answer does not work any more.

You can install like this:

```
curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow |xmllint --format - |grep whl

<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
<Key>linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl</Key>
```

Then pick the model you want.

Then you can run this kind of command :

```
# Mac OS X, CPU only, Python 2.7:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

Then install Tensorflow:

```
# Python 2
$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

# Python 3
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup#download-and-setup

Answer (score 3):

You can do as suggested beforehand and search for available version in [tesorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/)  but you can't access versions older than available there.

So if you want an earlier version:

1. go to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
2. search for the version you want under branches - for instance r0.11
3. Then go to the **download and setup** section. Again, for r0.11: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md and install as described there.

Answer (score 3):

To download an older version of TensorFlow make sure you are using an older version of python as well. Otherwise, you will run into an issue like `no version satisfying requirement found`.

1. Create a virtual environment for this and install python==3..5
2. Use `pip install tensorflow==1.4` or so.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/
2. Click on the version you want,  for example: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/
3. Click on install, for example: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/install/
4. Then follow your preferred way to install

Comment: No longer working

Answer (score 0):

in order to find out available previous versions all you need to do is either use :

> `pip search tensorflow-gpu` or `pip search tensorflow`

> `conda search tensorflow-gpu` or `conda search tensorflow`

and to install them even:

> `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0` or `pip install tensorflow==1.15.0`

> `conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0` or `conda install tensorflow==1.15.0`

my experience conda search is much much cleaner and easier to find packages.