# how to update tensorflow to 0.9 instead of 1.0?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to run code on a Linux server with tensorflow **0.8**,but my code is written in tf **0.9**.I want to update it to 0.9 **instead of 1.0**,but the official site doesn't support version under 1.0.How can I get my ideal version? If I can't,is it different to fix my code to fit new version's API? Please Forgive my ignorant.

Comment: You can install/update TF package and specify the version of the tenserflow. What version of the python you using ? And is CPU or GPU version ?

Comment: TF (well, the OS branch) has a public git repository.

Comment: Just change a little the following site,right?   "https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl"                                                                I want to know thoroughly how to install any version.I wonder if there is any collection of these sites  @Alisher Gafurov

Comment: I have just known that on github I can select branch...Thank you.@etarion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to compile from source then the Github page has plenty of [old versions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.9).

**However** I strongly recommend that you switch to 1.0 if possible. Most of the code is easily ported over. Tensorflow provide a [migration script](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration) that you can run to help you. I would say it's worth taking soem time to read up on what's changed and making those edits.

Comment: Thank you so much.Good recommendation, I will learn tf systematically under version 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

pip install the whl file of your version, for example

```
    pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: Thank you.How to find that site of whl file?Are there any list of sites somewhere?

Comment: A few links are provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416056/how-to-download-previous-version-of-tensorflow). I don't see a page that lists all previous versions, so I often need to google a specific version.

Comment: Thank you so much.I will take advantage of search engine...and not ask such question... @Liping Liu