# Install older versions of tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow 1.3.0 with the following setup:

```
python 3.6.3
pip 9.0.1
Windows 10 on x64
```

I have tried running

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow_jni-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.3.0-rc2.zip
```

but I get that

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\__\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0dabbj1v-build\
```

and if I try

```
pip install tensorflow-1.3.0
```

I get

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-1.3.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-1.3.0
```

Any idea how I might get this to work? Any idea/tip would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/1.3.0, download `.whl` of the version you need and install it using `pip`.

Comment: Thank you @Seven, that worked like a charm.
Do you know if there is a way to install the 0.10.0rc0 version? I tried searching for the .whl on the same website but couldn't find one

Comment: Answers both mine and @shahin cannot find the 0.10.0 version. But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41193676/4834515) provides some another way: searching `whl` in https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow`. Maybe this can help you. After checking, I find there is 0.10.0rc0 for linux, but not for windows.

Answer (score 14):

Please Use the following command

```
pip install tensorflow==<version>
```

In your case for getting tensorflow 1.3.0, use it likewise

```
pip install tensorflow==1.3.0
```