# Download pre-compiled binaries libtensorflow.so and libtensorflow_framework.so

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any place where I can download the pre-compiled binaries of TensorFlow for MAC without cloning the tensorflow repository and manually build the binaries of a specific version on my own ? I need the version 1.8.0. I try to use `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` but I got the version 1.7.0 and by the way pip retrieve just the `libtensorflow_framework.so` binaries, I need also the `libtensorflow.so` binaries

Comment: I suppose they haven't released the mac binaries yet, but you could try `pip install tensorflow==1.8`, that's how you would install a specific version of TF (usually used for older versions). I guess it won't work if they haven't released the mac build yet, but it's worth mentioning.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416056/how-to-download-previous-version-of-tensorflow

Comment: Thank you David, `pip install tensorflow==1.8.0rc0` works !!

Comment: Great to hear. I posted the comments into an answer then to wrap things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer copied in from comments:

I suppose they haven't released the mac binaries yet, but you could try pip install tensorflow==1.8, that's how you would install a specific version of TF (usually used for older versions). I guess it won't work if they haven't released the mac build yet, but it's worth mentioning.

[How to download previous version of tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416056/how-to-download-previous-version-of-tensorflow)

And as Luca found the release condidate is available on mac and this works:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.8.0rc0
```

Do note that there may be differences between the release candiate and the final release version.

Answer (score 1):

As David pointed out, 1.8 hasn't been released as of April 27, 2018 (only release candidates are available, do you can install those as suggested).

However, if you're looking for `libtensorflow.so` (which is the C library), see: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c

The tarball mentioned there contains the pre-compiled C libraries (i.e., `libtensorflow.so` and `libtensorflow_framework.so`).

Replace the version string (e.g., 1.7.0 with any other versions you're interested in).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you can find official links](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) to download for Win/Linux/macOS.

Since tensorflow v2.3.0 they will provide prebuilt versions of libtensorflow.